# Why not define the Lagrangian like this?

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier, constraints

Say I have a constrained optimisation problem where I need to minimize $f(x,y)$ subject to the constraint that $g(x,y) = c$.

The lagrangian is defined as

$$\mathcal{L}(x,y,\lambda)=f(x,y)+\lambda (g(x,y)-c)$$

and I think we attempt to minimize it in order to find a solution to our original optimisation problem.

The intuition that I'd like to use (if it's accurate), is that the minimising lagrangian is sort of a relaxed version of the original problem, where we have a "penalty" or "subsidy" when our constraint is not satisfied (as the function might take on a smaller or larger value).

But here, aren't we permitting the equality constraint to be violated, so long as the lagragian is minimised? Why not instead use

$$M(x,y)=f(x,y) + (g(x,y)-c)^2$$

and attempt to minimise this instead? Wouldn't this make the optimal value for the second term be $g(x,y) = c$? I was thinking maybe this function would give greater "importance" to satisfying the constraint, as all other values for $(x,y)$ would lead to an increase in $M(x,y)$.

Thanks!

Comment: @Brevan Ellefsen: your comment appears totally unrelated to the question. $L$ is not a generic ML penalty or loss function.

Comment: @symplectomorphic I agree. I was attempting to answer the question I felt the OP was trying to ask, instead of what the OP literally wrote. I've deleted it regardless, since you are right in that it is quite tangential

Comment: "$L$" is not a generic penality or loss function - thanks for this comment. I was under the impression that it was. When would you use a penalty function vs a lagrangian?

Comment: Here is the intuition. Assume you are minimizing $f(x)+\mu(g(x)-c)^2$. To get $g(x)=c$ one has to pick $\mu\to+\infty$ . Differentiation gives $$\nabla f(x)+\underbrace{2\mu(g(x)-c)}_{\lambda}\nabla g(x)=0.$$ Here we see that $\mu\to+\infty$ and $g(x)-c\to 0$, so the product is likely (or hopefully) to converge to something finite. The limit is the multiplier for the optimal point.

Comment: Boyd and Vanderbergh chapter 5 will clear this up. You use the Lagrangian to build lower bounds (for each lambda minimize over x), then the dual problem is to find the best lower bound - now take the supremum over lambda.

Answer (score 1):

You have misunderstood Lagrangian multipliers.

The theorem says that if $(x_0, y_0)$ is a constrained optimum (and the gradient of $g$ is nonzero), then there is a $\lambda_0$ such that $(x_0, y_0, \lambda_0)$ is a **stationary point**, *not necessarily a* **minimum**, of the Lagrangian function $L(x, y, \lambda)$. The stationary condition forces $g=c$, which you can see by taking the partial derivative of $L$ with respect to $\lambda$ and setting it to zero.

In fact, the stationary point of the Lagrangian that solves the original problem is never an extremum (maximum or minimum); see [this](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27765899?seq=1). (Even if you don’t have access, just read the first page of the preview.)

Thus your question makes little sense. In fact, all stationary points of $L$ *do* result in the constraint $g=c$ being satisfied.

Comment: Thanks! Yes indeed, it's possible I have misunderstood this. Could you please clarify the relation between Lagrange multipliers and the intuition of "moving constraints into the objective function" and the idea of Lagrange multipliers as a "shadow cost", which are terms I've heard which made me think about this

Comment: That’s an entirely different question. The question you actually asked makes no sense for the reason I give here: (1) you aren’t actually minimizing $L$, and (2) even if you were, minimizing $M$ doesn’t require that $g=c$.

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense. Yes, I was thinking about this transformation fallacy, but it appears to not be accurate. Can you illustrate what the "purpose" is of a lagrangian vs say a penalty function?

Comment: A “penalty” or “loss” function is just an objective function one wants to minimize (so it very well could be the function $f$ in your example, if you are seeking to minimize $f$). The concept also arises in statistics, where it is used to measure error in estimation theory. These are very different ideas than the Lagrangian.

Comment: Oh okay. So would it be right for me to say "the Lagrangian is more so a check for whether the necessary conditions for an analytic solution to the constraint problem to exist are satisfied?"